# Consulta PHP WampServer

Tags: php

tengo una duda pase un código en php de un servidor remoto a uno local para trabajar en intranet. estoy usando WampServer 3.1.0 de 64bits y el código que antes me funcionaba perfectamente ahora me esta fallando. lo que hago es recorrer un string y separar las letras de los numero pero me genera un error en todas las lineas donde aparece $cadena[$i] lo cual para mi no tiene sentido ya que se supone ya inicie el vector al pasarle el string en este caso A1 por lo que generaría 2 campos de memoria $cadena[0]="A" Y $cadena[1]="1" o al menos así funcionaba en el servidor remoto. no se por que ahora no funciona, que estoy haciendo mal?

**Notice: Uninitialized string offset**

$CodGrupo es un parametros que lleva por ejempl A1

```
 $Grupo='';
        $Conteo='';
        $cadena='';
        $Retorna="";
        $CodInventario="";
        $CargarCodInventario=false;
        $longitud =0;
        $cadena=$CodGrupo;
        $longitud = strlen($CodGrupo);

        $longitud = strlen($CodGrupo);
        for ($i=0; $i<=$longitud ;$i++){
             if(is_numeric($cadena[$i])) {
                    //es numero
                    if($CargarCodInventario==true){
                        $CodInventario=$CodInventario.$cadena[$i];
                    }else{
                        $Conteo=$Conteo.$cadena[$i];
                    }
              }else{
                        //no es numerico
                    //busca el guion 
                    if($cadena[$i]=="-"){
                         $CargarCodInventario=true;
                    }else{
                        $Grupo=$Grupo.$cadena[$i];
                    }



            }


        }//fin for
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es `$longitud=2` cuando `$CodGrupo = 'A1'` y el loop se detendrá cuando `$i` sea menor o igual a 2, por tanto el indice `i` sea igual a 2 seguirá entrando y `$cadena` de 2 no esta fuera del rango. Para solucionar este problema cambia la condición en tu `for` de `<=` a `<`.